# Why bigint lacks bitwise NOT operator (~~~) in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, operator-overloading, biginteger

<strike>Recently I've spotted an oddity in `System.Numerics.BigInteger` [type definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) that seemingly lacks a justification - this type [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986593.aspx) bitwise `NOT` operator (`~~~` in F#).</strike> While other integer types in F# allow performing bit negation <strike>and overall in .NET ecosystem</strike>, `bigint` type lacks correspondent `~~~` operator.

The fact that `bigint` is a synthetic type not directly supported by underlying hardware does not prevent it from supporting other bitwise operators, namely `<<<`, `>>>`, `|||`, `^^^`, and `&&&` that accommodate for the lack of preset bit width. So why `~~~` cannot?

**EDIT :** Thanks to [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) for pointing to my oversight of `System.Numerics.BigInteger` type having `OnesComplement` operator performing exactly `bitwise NOT`, indeed. I've corrected the original question accordingly. It makes me to believe that `~~~` was omitted from `bigint` operators in F# inadvertently.

Comment: `BigInteger bi1 = 1; var bi2 = ~bi1;` will be `-2` ....

Comment: You didn't look closely enough, for the operator is in the list you linked, see [OnesComplement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_onescomplement.aspx). As the above comment by @I4V shows, this operator works fine in some .NET languages. So the question is why is it (apparently) not supported in F#? I don't know F# very well, so I can't answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define missing `bitwise NOT (~~~)` operator for `bigint` as

```
let inline (~~~) x = bigint.op_OnesComplement x
```

then we would be able checking its actual properties with regard to double negation

```
let ``Double Negation`` x =
    if ~~~ (~~~ x) <> x then
        failwith "Ka-Boom!!"

``Double Negation`` 0I
``Double Negation`` -1I
``Double Negation`` 9999999999I
```

all returning `unit`, and [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
let ``De Morgan's Laws`` p q =
    if not
        ((~~~(p &&& q)) = ((~~~p) ||| (~~~q)) &&
        (~~~(p ||| q)) = ((~~~p) &&& (~~~q)))
    then
        failwith "Ka-Boom!!"

``De Morgan's Laws`` 0I 0I
``De Morgan's Laws`` 0I -1I
``De Morgan's Laws`` -1I 0I
```

all returning `unit` too.

While playing with above snippets the observed perfect code behavior seemingly prompts for reporting the matter with `bigint ~~~` to `fsbugs@microsoft.com` for correction.

Comment: Well, the issue is the symbolic name that F# uses for `~~~` is `op_LogicalNot`, not `op_OnesComplement`, which was perhaps an unfortunate decision but which won't be changed now.  The compiler synthesizes artificial members for the integral types (just as it does for other arithmetic operators).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is necessarily the reason, but the lack of a fixed width means that `~~~` won't satisfy some nice properties that it usually does.  For instance, what should `~~~ 5I` be?  Logically, this should be `0x1111...1010` (with an infinite prefix of ones).  Obviously we need to trim this prefix somewhere.  If we keep the result the same bit-width as the input, then we get `010 = 2` as the result.  But since leading zeros don't matter, the same logic dictates that `~~~ 2I` should be `1I`.  But then `~~~ (~~~ 5I) <> 5I`.

Comment: Java's BigInteger class solves this by keeping the identity `~x == -1-x`, so the twos-complement representation has an infinite prefix of ones like you describe.

Comment: @finnw .NET _does_ have the operation, see [`BigInteger.op_OnesComplement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_onescomplement.aspx).